# document.ready function being called over and over

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication

I have an html site that doesn't have page changes. It just loads different elements into each position on the page using ajax calls. I need my login function to run after the page is loaded the first time (because it requires elements on index to exist), but when I use $(document).ready(login), it fires every time an element is loaded (since it loads elements onto the page, it gets stuck in an infinite loop). Other than placing it at the bottom of my index page (which seems pretty fragile) is there a way to make it load after the index page is finished loading, but not have it run everytime an ajax request adds something to the page?

My login function looks like this:

```
function login ()
{
    if($.cookie('employee'))
        employee = $.cookie('employee');

    if(employee && !employee.login)
        $("div.middle").load('login.html');
    else
            $("div.middle").load('main.html');

}

function logout ()
{
    //FIXME send a logout request to server to end session also
    employee = null;
    $.cookie('employee', null);
    $("div.middle").load('login.html'); 
}
```

and my initial ready function looks like:
//Global variables
var employee = new Object;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.leftColumn").html(buildLeftNav());
        //set height of middle if height of leftColumn is less than height of middle
        if($("div.leftColumn").css('height') < $("div.middle").css('height'))
            $("div.center").css('height' , $('div.middle').css('height'));




        //handle login and logout
        $.cookie.json = true;
        login();


    });
```

I have set up a fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/uZVP4/

Comment: The fiddle is not working.

Comment: It can't work because it doesn't have access to login.html or main.html, I just wanted to give you a full picture of the code

Comment: It appears that every time $('whatever').load() is called, $(document).ready() is initiated (and so is every document.ready that exists on that page).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem likely lies not in `document.ready` but that you are likely loading the same script over and over in the AJAX calls. Since script automatically loads new content, it is creating an infinite loop of load new content which causes new content to load again..over and over.

If you must keep the scripts in remote pages you could use `$.get` which will not execute scripts within ajax content

Answer (score 2):

Normally `$(document).ready()` is only called ONCE per page.

If you want a 'hacky' solution you could set a variable

`var wasReady = false;`

and in `$(document).ready()` set that value to `true` if it is `false`, otherwise do nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(!wasReady)
 wasReady = true;
else return;
...
}
```

I usually use

```
$(function(){
 /* code here */
});
```

which is the same as document ready, but if you want to execute javascript after all the page has loaded (including images) use

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
 /*code here */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue got "resolved" for us by using ".one"

```
$(document).one("ready", function () {
   // code
});
```

Comment: This is really a hack, it works for some and not others.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put it in the onload from the body tag, putting it here only run each time the form is submitted.

```
....
<body onload="login()">
....
```

Comment: I am trying to keep all of my JS in an external document (I am going to minify it all when I am done developing. Thanks though.